# Strange code execution: should assign one element, assigns all

Tags: ruby, arrays, genetic-algorithm

I am trying to write a genetic algorithm for function approximation. A part of the code responsible for mutation of one gene changes the whole chromosome array. It even changes another array that is not used in this part. Here's the code.

```
print "\n\nchrom_array5: ", @chrom_array    
print "\n\nchrom_array5: ", @chrom_array    
random = rand

if @no_of_chrom*@no_of_variables*@mutation_rate > random  

  z=( rand * @no_of_chrom ).to_i        
  print "\n\nz: ", z        
  v=( rand * @no_of_variables).to_i        
  print "\n\nv: ", v        
  ble=new_chrom_array[0][0]        
  print "\nnew_chrom_array[0][0]: ", new_chrom_array        
  new_chrom_array[z][v] =   ble + ble*rand - ble*random        
  print "\nnew_chrom_array[z][v]: ", new_chrom_array 

end      

print "\n\nchrom_array6: ", @chrom_array      
print "\nnew_chrom_array6: ", new_chrom_array      

@chrom_array = new_chrom_array      
 ...
```

Here's the output from a mutating iteration:

> chrom_array5: [[128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78],  [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78]]
>
> new_chrom_array5: [[128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78]]
>
> z: 2
>
> v: 0
>
> new_chrom_array[0][0]: [[128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78],
>   [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78], [128383853580908.78]]
>
> new_chrom_array[z][v]: [[143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22]]
>
> chrom_array6: [[143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22]]
>
> new_chrom_array6: [[143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22],
>   [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22], [143481948278275.22]]

Do you know the reason for such behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

One way this can happen is if all the elements of your new_chrom_array contain the same object. For example, using `irb` to interactively execute ruby code:

```
~ ∙ irb
irb(main):001:0> sub_array = [1]
=> [1]
irb(main):002:0> array1 = [sub_array, sub_array, sub_array]
=> [[1], [1], [1]]
irb(main):003:0> array2 = [sub_array, sub_array, sub_array, sub_array]
=> [[1], [1], [1], [1]]
irb(main):004:0> array1[1][0] = 'x'
=> "x"
irb(main):005:0> array1
=> [["x"], ["x"], ["x"]]
irb(main):006:0> array2
=> [["x"], ["x"], ["x"], ["x"]]
```

So here making an assignment to `array[1][0]` affects both `array1` and `array2` because the object in all of their elements is `sub_array`.

This can be confirmed by looking at the `object_id` of the array elements:

```
irb(main):007:0> array1[0].object_id
=> 70353532235320
irb(main):008:0> array1[1].object_id
=> 70353532235320
irb(main):009:0> array2[1].object_id
=> 70353532235320
```

In my experience there are a couple of things which cause this:

Creating an array using `Array.new` like this which will use the same object for all of the elements:

```
irb(main):010:0> a = Array.new(5, ['x'])
=> [["x"], ["x"], ["x"], ["x"], ["x"]]
irb(main):011:0> a[0].object_id
=> 70353539884820
irb(main):012:0> a[4].object_id
=> 70353539884820
```

You can avoid this by using a block to initialize the elements, as the block will return a new object each time it is called - note the different `object_id`s

```
irb(main):013:0> b = Array.new(5) {['x']}
=> [["x"], ["x"], ["x"], ["x"], ["x"]]
irb(main):014:0> b[0].object_id
=> 70353535993240
irb(main):015:0> b[4].object_id
=> 70353535992900
```

The second common problem is the use of `.dup` to make copies of an array and not remembering that it makes a *shallow* copy:

```
irb(main):016:0> a1 = [['x']]
=> [["x"]]
irb(main):017:0> a2 = a1.dup
=> [["x"]]
irb(main):018:0> a2[0][0] = 'y'
=> "y"
irb(main):019:0> a1
=> [["y"]]
irb(main):020:0> a2
=> [["y"]]
```

You can use `object_id` to see what the contents of the arrays are.  One way to get a *deep* copy which divorces the copy from the original is to use ruby's `Marshal` to make a copy of the data structure - here we see that altering `a3` doesn't affect `a1`

```
irb(main):021:0> a3 = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(a1))
=> [["y"]]
irb(main):022:0> a3[0][0] = 'z'
=> "z"
irb(main):023:0> a1  
=> [["y"]]
```